# How to log file contents in request body of a multipart/form-data request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, logging

I am trying to log all requests in my asp.net web API project to a text file. I am using `DelegationHandler` feature to implement logging mechanism in my application, below is the code snippet for that,

```
public class MyAPILogHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           // Captures all properties from the request.
            var apiLogEntry = CreateApiLogEntryWithRequestData(request);
            if (request.Content != null)
            {
                    await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                        .ContinueWith(task =>
                        {
                            apiLogEntry.RequestContentBody = task.Result;
                        }, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    var response = task.Result;

                    // Update the API log entry with response info
                    apiLogEntry.ResponseStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                    apiLogEntry.ResponseTimestamp = DateTime.Now;

                    if (response.Content != null)
                    {
                        apiLogEntry.ResponseContentBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        apiLogEntry.ResponseContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                        apiLogEntry.ResponseHeaders = SerializeHeaders(response.Content.Headers);
                    }   

                    var logger = new LogManager();
                    logger.Log(new LogMessage()
                    {
                       Message = PrepareLogMessage(apiLogEntry),
                       LogTo = LogSource.File
                    });

                    return response;
                }, cancellationToken);
        }
}
```

Above implementation is working as expected and it is logging all required request/response information to the file.

But when we make any multipart/form-data POST api call with some images attached, after logging this request, log file becomes huge, because all image/binary content is getting converted into string and writing down it the text file. please find below log file content,

```
Body: 
----------------------------079603462429865781513947
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="batchid"

22649EEE-3994-4225-AF73-D9A6B659CAE3
----------------------------079603462429865781513947
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="d.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG


IHDR    í   %v ¸   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa      pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d  ÿ¥IDATx^ìýX]K¶(
·îsß»ß÷þï{O÷iÛ    Á2âîîîÁe¹âîî,<@   Á$÷w_ÈZó5$Dwvv×}
----------------------------4334344396037865656556781513947
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="m.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG


IHDR    í   %v ¸   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa      pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d  ÿ¥IDATx^ìýX]K¶(
·îsß»ß÷þï{O÷iÛ    Á2âîîîÁe¹âîî,<@   Á$÷w_ÈZó5$Dwvv×}
```

I don't want to log the binary content of a request body, it could be sufficient to log only request body file contents like,

```
    ----------------------------079603462429865781513947
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="batchid"

    22649EEE-3994-4225-AF73-D9A6B659CAE3
    ----------------------------079603462429865781513947
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="d.png"
    Content-Type: image/png

    ----------------------------4334344396037865656556781513947
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="m.png"
    Content-Type: image/png
```

Can you please suggest how to prevent logging binary content of request body and log only file contents of a request body.

Comment: I have updated my existing answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, you are implementing something similar to [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/asp-net-web-api-request-response-usage-logging) approach.
When uploading a file (i.e., a request type **"multipart/form-data"**) its actual content always begins with the *"Content-Type: {ContentTypeValue}\r\n\r\n*" sequence and the next header begins with *"\r\n--"* sequence (as it is illustrated in your logs). You can explore more info about raw request data parsing at [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,402). So, you can strip everything about file (if exists), for example, via RegEx:

Content-Type: {ContentTypeOrOctetStream}\r\n\r\n{FileContentBytesToRemove}\r\n

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
string StripRawFileContentIfExists(string input) {
    if(input.IndexOf("Content-Type") == -1)
        return input;
    string regExPattern = "(?<ContentTypeGroup>Content-Type: .*?\\r\\n\\r\\n)(?<FileRawContentGroup>.*?)(?<NextHeaderBeginGroup>\\r\\n--)";
    return Regex.Replace(input, regExPattern, me => me.Groups["ContentTypeGroup"].Value + string.Empty + me.Groups["NextHeaderBeginGroup"].Value);
}
...
//apiLogEntry.RequestContentBody = task.Result;
apiLogEntry.RequestContentBody = StripRawFileContentIfExists(task.Result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I will try this approach and let you know the result. Many thanks!!!

Comment: You can test it first with a sample application by using the existing request log from your above post as an input. Possibly, you will want to tune up the final code according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest separate `huge content` from log. like you encountered, it just screws everything up in the log. to some extent disables log functionality.

I'd suggest you organize those `huge content` in file system. like this:

```
---request-a/
  |--request-a-body-multi-part1.txt
  |--request-a-body-multi-part2.txt
```

and just maintain a link in your log to reference this file system path.

hope it helps.